# C++ Multiple Inheritance Question

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

The scenario generating this is quite complex so I'll strip out a few pieces and give an accurate representation of the classes involved.

```
/* This is inherited using SI by many classes, as normal */
class IBase
{
 virtual string toString()=0;
};

/* Base2 can't inherit IBase due to other methods on IBase which aren't appropriate */
class Base2
{
 string toString()
 {
  ...
 }
};

/* a special class, is this valid? */
class Class1 : public IBase, public Base2
{
};
```

So, is this valid? Will there be conflicts on the toString? Or can Class1 use Base2::toString to satisfy IBase?
Like I say there are lots of other things not shown, so suggestions for major design changes on this example are probably not that helpful... though any general suggestions/advice are welcome.

My other thought was something like this:

```
class Class1 : public IBase, public Base2
{
 virtual string toString()
 {
   return Base2::toString();
 }
};
```

This builds and links, but I've no idea if it has hidden bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this using "virtual inheritance".

Consider creating a common base class that *only* defines a pure virtual `toString` method (or, in reality, pure virtual version of whatever methods it makes sense for both `IBase` and `Base2` to have), e.g.

```
class Stringable {
  public:
    virtual string toString() = 0;
};
```

Then, have both `IBase` and `Base2` inherit from this `Stringable` class:

```
class IBase : public Stringable
{
};

class Base2 : public Stringable
{
public:
   virtual string toString()
   { ... }
};
```

Now this as it is still won't work because `Class1` will have inherited *two* copies of the `Stringable` base class, only one of which has an implementation for `toString` in its inheritance hierarchy. This is known as the "[dreaded diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8)". However, if `IBase` and `Base2` were to inherit *virtually* from `Stringable`, like this:

```
class IBase : virtual public Stringable
{
};

class Base2 : virtual public Stringable
{
public:
   virtual string toString()
   { ... }
};
```

Then this tells the compiler that there should only be one common `Stringable` base class even if `IBase` and `Base2` are both inherited by one class, which is exactly what you want, because then the `Base2::toString` is used for `Class1`.

Your second idea has no "hidden bugs", but is somewhat of a pain in the butt to implement repeatedly, as you probably realize.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine.

You're properly overriding the IBase interface to provide a definition of `ToString()` that will be forwared up to `Base2::ToString()`.

Note that `Base2` doesn't declare toString() as virtual, so `Class1` can't override the behavior of `Base2::ToString`.  No ambiguity there.

And, in addition, this is not the classic diamond problem in multiple inheritance solved by [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) because they don't share a base class.